# Test fails when adding ":remember_token"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm following chapter 8 of Michale Hartl's tutorial. When I add:

```
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
```

to the user_spec.rb file the test fails, with the failure notice pointing directly to this one line in the file.

Prior to adding this line, all tests past.

The only other steps I took after adding this line (and before running the test) was to run a remember token:

```
$ rails generate migration add_remember_token_to_users
```

I then updated db/migrate/[timestamp]_add_remember_token_to_users.rb as follows:

```
class AddRememberTokenToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :remember_token, :string
    add_index  :users, :remember_token
  end
end
```

and development and test databases as usual:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```

Comment: I tried to rollback the database and then migrate again, but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Did you restart your spork server after you migrated the database?

Comment: Restarting the spork server worked. Thanks!!! Submit an answer and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Spork` caches the rails environment it does not know about the migration until it is restarted.

Therefore you need to restart the `Spork` server so that it will reload the rails environment including the new migrations.

Comment: Solved the problem. Thanks for your help!